# ListView Not Working On Real Device

Tags: android, listview

I have a problem with my listview, it works on emulator but not on real device. I tested with 2 real devices and it does not populate. I get listview data from database using json. Json result is ok as it prints to logcat and populates listview on emulator.

ListView Java:

```
        public class ActivityRequestsFrom extends MainActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    ______________________________________________________________________________

    Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_requests_from);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listRequests);

    RequestsAdapter adapter = new RequestsAdapter(this, arrRequest_Name, arrRequest_Number, 
            arrRequest_Username, arrRequest_Result, imageId);

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);     
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        }

    ______________________________________________________________________________

    class RequestsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
                {
                    Context context;
                    List<String> Request_Name;
                    List<String> Request_Number;
                    List<String> Request_Username;
                    List<String> Request_Result;
                    Integer[] imgid;

    RequestsAdapter(Context c, List<String> Request_Name, 
                    List<String> Request_Number, List<String> Request_Username,
                    List<String> Request_Result, Integer[] imgid)
                    {

    super(c, R.layout.activity_requests_single, R.id.textName, Request_Name);
                    this.context=c;
                    this.Request_Name=Request_Name; 
                    this.Request_Number=Request_Number; 
                    this.Request_Username=Request_Username; 
                    this.Request_Result=Request_Result; 
                    this.imgid=imgid;   
                    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View row=convertView;               
    if(row==null)
        {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_requests_single, parent, false);       }
    TextView txtName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textName);
    TextView txtNumber = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textNumber);
    TextView txtUsername = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textUsername);
    TextView txtResult = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textResult);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Map<String, Integer> drawableMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    drawableMap.put("ok",R.drawable.request_pending_from);
    drawableMap.put("pending",R.drawable.request_pending_from);         
    drawableMap.put("rejected",R.drawable.request_rejected_from);
            drawableMap.put("blocked",R.drawable.request_blocked_from);
            txtName.setText(Request_Name.get(position));
            txtNumber.setText(Request_Number.get(position));
            txtUsername.setText(Request_Username.get(position));
            txtResult.setText(Request_Result.get(position));
            //imageView.setImageResource(imgid[position]);
    imageView.setImageResource(drawableMap.get(Request_Result.get(position).toLowerCase()));
    return row;
                        }
                    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    TextView tvUsername = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textUsername);
    usernameSelected = tvUsername.getText().toString();

    TextView tvResult = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textResult);
    resultSelected = tvResult.getText().toString();

    if (resultSelected.equals("Pending"))
        {
        pendingOptions();                   
        }

    else if (resultSelected.equals("Rejected"))
        {
        rejectedOptions();  
        }

    else if (resultSelected.equals("Blocked"))
        {
        blockedOptions();   

        }

    else
        {
        }


    }
```

ListView Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listRequest"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</ListView>
```

ListView Single Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/LLdummy"
    android:text="Name"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
     />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textUsername"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textNumber"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textNumber"
    android:text="Username"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textNumber"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textName"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textName"
    android:text="Number"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/LLdummy"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/request_pending_to" />
```

Json

```
private class JsonReadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
       HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
       HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
       try {
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        jsonResult = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
       }


       catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return null;
      }

      private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
       String rLine = "";
       StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
       BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

       try {
        while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
         answer.append(rLine);
        }
       }

       catch (IOException e) {
        // e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error..." + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
       return answer;
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try{  
       ListDrwaer(); //has ConnectionException (when it cannot reach server)
        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please check your connection..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
      }
     }// end async task

     public void accessWebService() {
      JsonReadTask task = new JsonReadTask();
      // passes values for the urls string array
      task.execute(new String[] { "http://server/file.php?pIMEI="+IMEI });
      }

     // build hash set for list view
     public void ListDrwaer() {

      try {
       JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
       JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("request_info");

       for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);

        String request_name = jsonChildNode.optString("Request_Name");
        String request_number = jsonChildNode.optString("Request_Number");
        String request_username = jsonChildNode.optString("Request_Username");
        String request_result = jsonChildNode.optString("Request_Result");

        arrRequest_Name.add(request_name);
        arrRequest_Number.add(request_number);
        arrRequest_Username.add(request_username);
        arrRequest_Result.add(request_result);

        System.out.println("Request_Name: "+request_name);
        System.out.println("Request_Number: "+request_number);
        System.out.println("Request_Username: "+request_username);
        System.out.println("Request_Result: "+request_result);

       }
      } catch (JSONException e) {
          System.out.println("Json Error Requests" +e.toString());
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Requests Pending", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      }
}
```

Call Async

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_requests_from);

     ...

    accessWebService();

    //ListView
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listRequests);

    RequestsAdapter adapter = new RequestsAdapter(this, arrRequest_Name, arrRequest_Number, arrRequest_Username, arrRequest_Result, imageId);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Comment: Where/when/how are you filling those lists?

Comment: is there any force close happen?

Comment: @codeMagic i edited to include json code where i add data to listview

Comment: @AliAbdolahi i do not think I have such

Comment: You haven't said when/where you call that AysncTask...

Comment: @codeMagic I call it on onCreate just before I initialize the listView and set the listview adapter, note the system.out.printlines in json code return data correctly from db, problem comes with listView showing on real device (i have added an edit to show AysncTask call)

Comment: That's the problem as I suspected. The lists aren't populated by the time you set the adapter because of the **Asynchrounous** task. You need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` in `onPostExecute()` on the Adapter

Comment: @codeMagic Wow!!! That did it! thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the data isn't received when the `Adapter` is set on the `ListView`. This is because the data is populated in an `AysncTask` which is **async** hronous by nature. This means that it will run in the background while the other code runs (i.e. the `ListView` populating.

So, in `onPostExecute()` you need to use `notifyDataSetChanged()` to let the `ListView` know that there is new items to populate.

```
@Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // your code

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // this line here
 }// end async task
```

In your example, this will obviously require you making the `Adapter` a member variable or passing it to your `AsyncTask`.

Comment: so it is safe to assume that an emulator runs background tasks quicker than an actual device.

Comment: @user3560827 No, I would not assume that. It could happen that the task finishes beforehand on occasion on a real device. The important thing to know is that it may or may not (but most likely will not) finish before the other code runs. So always make sure you account for that and put the relevant code in the appropriate places.